# How can I move a JPanel on a JFrame in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

So I want to make a simple pong like game from scratch with java.
I am currently making the movement of the two paddles.
However, I've got stucked at the very beginning.
I am trying to set the starting position of the 2 paddles, but I can not.
I was trying by setting custom layouts, but later I want to change their positions constantly by moving them of course.

I've the following code:

```
package com.kristof;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("gEngine");
        Player playerOne = new Player();
        Player playerTwo = new Player();

        frame.add(playerOne.getMyPanel());
        frame.add(playerTwo.getMyPanel());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBackground(Color.RED);
        frame.setSize(1280, 720);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class Player {
        private JPanel myPanel;

        public Player() {
            this.myPanel = new MyPanel();
        }

        public JPanel getMyPanel() {
            return myPanel;
        }

    }

    static class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        public MyPanel() {
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // let the component be painted "natural"
            super.paintComponent(g);
            // Do custom painting
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(50, getHeight() / 2, 20, 120);
        }
    }

}
```

I've already tried changing their positions by calling the `setLocation` method on their `myPanel`s, but that did not work.

Comment: The first two things I would expect to see are 1) an [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).  This even handler would trigger a 2) [repaint() or update()](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) on one or more components.  SUGGESTION: Google for "java swing pong game" and work through one or more of the on-line tutorials you'll find.

Comment: Yeah I know but firstly I would like to know how can I move them without any key presses.

Comment: @paulsm4 yeah I was thinking about that but with this project I want to work on my own and not copy the code of other people.

Comment: Copying good code - and learning from it - beats the heck out of wasting time floundering ... along with the very real risk of picking up bad habits from bad code that merely "seems to work".  Just saying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you created a Player class, but you dont have the position of a player in that class.

Since the paddles will only be moving up and down we only need methods for changing the y coordinate.

```
  static class Player{
    int x;
    int y;

   Player(int x){this.x=x;}

   void moveUp(){y--;}
   void moveDown(){y++;}

   void drawPlayer(Graphics2D g){
       g.fillRect(x,y,40,120);
   }

}
```

---

Now in the class that extends JPanel (in your case `MyPanel`) we can take our newly created `Player` class as input (by putting it in the constructor)

We can also create a timer so the frames refresh regularly.
By adding `players[0].moveDown;` in the clock, the first paddle will move down every frame

In the paint method we can iterate over the players and display them by using the `drawPlayer` method in the `Player`class.

```
 MyPanel(Player[] players) {
        this.players = players;
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                repaint();
                players[0].moveDown;
            }
        }, 300, 1000 / 60);
    }

 @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        for(Player p : players){
            p.drawPlayer((Graphics2D) g);
        }
    }
```

---

Now to put it all together we just need to create the players when we start the program.

```
Player[] players = new Player[]{
            new Player(100),
            new Player(1000)
    };
    frame.add(new PongWindow(players));
```

---

Here is how the code will look like all together:

```html
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    public class Main {
        

        public static void main(String[] args) {



            JFrame frame = new JFrame("gEngine");

            Player[] players = new Player[]{
                    new Player(100),
                    new Player(1000)
            };
            frame.add(new PongWindow(players));


            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setBackground(Color.RED);
            frame.setSize(1280, 720);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setVisible(true);




        }


        static class Player{
            int x;
            int y;

            Player(int x){this.x=x;}

            void moveUp(){y+= -8;}
            void moveDown(){y+= 8;}

            void drawPlayer(Graphics2D g){
                g.fillRect(x,y,40,120);
            }

        }


        static class PongWindow extends JPanel {

            //private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            Player[] players;

            PongWindow(Player[] players) {
                this.players = players;
                setBackground(Color.BLACK);

                new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        repaint();
                        players[0].moveDown();
                    }
                }, 300, 1000 / 60);


            }



            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

                for(Player p : players){
                    p.drawPlayer((Graphics2D) g);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I could tell you how you would implement key inputs, but from reading your comments it seems you are not interested in that

Comment: Well I am interested in that as well. Firstly I was trying to make this game with paddles as images and I had problems with implementing the key inputs as well.

Comment: Here is what you could do to add keyboard input:https://pastebin.com/PEFyx41W

Comment: In the answer's code, is the drawPlayer() method necessary? In the MyPanel class I have already got paintComponent in the original code which does the same I think

Comment: I used paint(), i am unsure exactly what the paintComponent does. Of course you could draw the rectangle directly in the paint method, then you would need to create a getY() method for the Player class to draw in the correct position

Comment: Oh, well. I have one more question. If I want to set the starting position of the paddles to the half of the frame's height, where should I tell it to be getHeight()/2?

Comment: In the Paint() method use: super.getHeight() and super.getWidth()

Comment: @Jesper Hustad - your answers are good.  But I think Gero Kristof is doing himself a grave disservice by playing [blind man groping the elephant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_men_and_an_elephant).

Comment: @paulsm4 sure, you are probably right. Tough I myself started coding recently and I find just having working  code and playing with it over time does give you a understanding of what is happening.